# Spark implementation for Locality Sensitive Hashing

Tags: apache-spark, locality-sensitive-hash

As part of a project I'm doing for my studies I'm looking for a way to use the hashing function of LSH with Spark. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this implementation:

https://github.com/mrsqueeze/spark-hash

Quoting from the README, "this implementation was largely based on the algorithm described in chapter 3 of Mining of Massive Datasets" which has a great description of LSH and minhashing.

Comment: @user3636583 please let us know how it fares for your use cases, especially versus FLANN, ANNOY, nearpy, SparseLSH, LSHForest (scikit-learn) etc. Personally I found the above Spark implementation to be very memory hungry.

Answer (score 1):

The recently released version of Spark (2.1.0) provides built-in support for LSH, but apparently only [in the Scala API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSH) (not in PySpark yet).